# React.useCallback not updating with dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using the following component to submit comments in my app:

```
const App = () => {
    const [text, setText] = React.useState("");

    const send = React.useCallback(() => {
        setText("");
        console.log("sending", text);
    }, [text]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const handler = e => {
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 13: // enter
                    if (e.shiftKey) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        send();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        
        document.addEventListener("keydown", handler);
        return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", handler);
    }, []);

    return <div className="App">
        <textarea
            className="App__text"
            value={text}
            onChange={e => {
                setText(e.target.value);
            }} />
        <button className="App__send" onClick={send}>send</button>
    </div>;
};
```

**[working demo here](https://codepen.io/SandoCalrissian/pen/JjXjYoQ?editors=0010)**

It's a simple text field and button.  When either the button, or shift-enter are pressed, the text in the text field is sent to the server (here we just `console.log` it).

The button works fine - enter `"hello world"` (or whatever) press the button, and the console will say `hello world`.

*Shift-enter, however, always prints an empty string.*

I'm guessing I'm misunderstanding `useCallback`.  As I understand it, `useCallback` wraps your function.  When one of the dependencies change, React swaps out your function without changing the wrapper function so it's still an up-to-date reference wherever it's used.  Given that the `send` being called in `useEffect` appears to have the initial value of `text` in scope, but the one used in the `onClick` of the `button` has the newest, my assumptions seem incorrect.

I've also tried adding `text` as a dependency of the `useEffect` but

- I don't want to remove/create/add the listener on every keystroke and
- It's still missing the last character pressed anyway.

**How can I keep a current version of my `send` function inside of another callback?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing `send` in your dependencies, take a look at this updated code:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  const handler = e => {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 13: // enter
        if (e.shiftKey) {
          e.preventDefault();
          send(); // This will always be called an older version, instead of updated one
        }
        break;
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("keydown", handler);
  return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", handler);
}, [send]); // You need to put send here, since it is part of this component, and needs to be updated
```

The reason It works with it, is because `send` function is memoised as well:

```js
const send = React.useCallback(() => {
  setText("");
  console.log("sending", text);
}, [text]);
```

so you need to make sure to update to its newer version, with its newer text (which never happened, thats why you got no text in your SHIFT+ENTER)

**EDIT: Upon further investigation, it seems to me that the biggest problem was out-of sync text and listener handler**.

I have modified the code to work, by removing the listener alltogether, and using `onKeyDown` prop directly on textarea. Take a look at this working codepen:

https://codepen.io/antonioerda/pen/zYqYWgx

Comment: This has the same problems as using `text` as a dependency: (1) it removes/adds the keydown callback every key-press (2) the last character is always cut off since the `useEffect` is delayed by 1 frame.  Additionally, if I just use `send` as a dependency, what's the point of using `useCallback`?

Comment: you should `useCallback` when you want to memoise functions which are hard to compute, and only to update on specific changes, instead of any change. I would recommend putting the `useCallback` here, and to fix (1) problem, you could separate it into different useEffects, I will update answer with example

Comment: @SandyGifford I understand your problem now, I've been fiddling with the code for some time, and managed to get to some answer, take a look at my codepen

Comment: ahhhh of course.  Big derp on my part.  I still think there is an interesting question in here if you don't have an event-driven component, but I think I'll post it in another question.  Thanks!

Comment: It fooled me as well, I didn't even understand your issue at first :) Glad we solved this, do you want me to remove the codepen, since it is your code, but a copy is on my profile now? I want to leave it for future answers, nothing else, I dont even use my codepen

Comment: So, funny story - I was using a CodePen template that I had made back when hooks were in beta still and `useEffect` didn't get called on the first frame.  This is why the last character was getting truncated all the time.  Here's a sperate pen with a new custom hooik `usePersistentCallback` which has the behavior I thought `useCallback` had.  https://codepen.io/SandoCalrissian/pen/poyoLpO

Comment: Omg... you saved me! Moving it to `onKeyDown` instead made it so much simpler and it just works whether I use `useCallback` or not!

Answer (score 0):

Two things to make sure you do when using the useCallback hook:

1. make sure to add the list of all the needed dependencies that are external to the method are listed.
2. if inside this method with the usecallback you call another method that you created using the usecallback, include the dependencies there in this one as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).